# Difference between asking questions on apple.stackexchange.com & stackoverflow.com with the iOS tag

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I have been using SO for the past one year, and a few days before I saw that there is one another site of SO i.e. [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

What is difference between asking question on [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com) & [SO site](https://stackoverflow.com/) with the `ios` tag? Is there any benefit of audience and experts present on any particular site? I am not able to understand the concept.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is scope.

Ask Different focuses on [Apple products](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), like general hardware, software, and services.

Stack Overflow is expected to have specific questions relating to programming or writing programs; since you've chosen iOS as your example, they would have to be explicitly for iOS.

So yes, there's a huge difference between the two.  If you ask an Objective C question on Ask Different, expect it to be closed.  Likewise, if you ask a question about how to install software on a Mac at Stack Overflow, expect it to be closed.

There are plenty of Apple enthusiasts and experts that are not programmers, so it makes sense to have a site that's scoped to that niche.  Likewise, there are a lot of programmers that are experts in Objective C, so it makes sense to cater to that niche too.